# HDD gives "failed to probe the device" (udisks-error-quark,0)

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, gparted, udisks

I run ubuntu on an SSD and was planning to use my HDD for storage purposes. I was running an ATA enhanced secure erase on the HDD when my PC crashed with an error that said NMI watchdog had detected an error on a CPU. I restarted the computer and tried formatting the drive but it gives the error mentioned. I ran the SMART test from the disks application and the overall assessment says that the disk is OK.

However, when i run blkid only my SSD is seen and my HDD (sdb) does not show up. Running lsblk results in sdb showing up with the type of disk. Tried using gparted and a lot of Input/Output errors show up at the scanning stage. dev/sdb is listed as 931.5GB and it shows file system as unallocated. However any attempt at creating a partition table is followed by numerous errors of the type "Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sdb; Input/output error".

How do i proceed in this situation, and is there any chance to get the drive back in working condition or is it dead?